# у меня не выводит данные с таблицы db mysql через hibernate spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

я не знаю что я делаю не так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я так понимаю что в cat должны приходить данные а их там нет ((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этой картинке, только на следующем breakpoint переменная `cat` получит свой `List`.

Comment: это типа как ? а пример есть где то а то я не понимаю (((как получить лист что мне ещё надо прописать ?

Comment: @Евгений нажми продолжить выполнение и на следующей красной точке должeн появиться твой `List` с БД

Comment: у меня появилась ошибка Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Comment: а листа так и нет (((

Comment: @Евгений убери лист как поле класса,   результат жди за после этого метода

Comment: return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Categories").list();

Comment: это типа так что ли ?